# Powershell - count files with same name pattern

Tags: powershell

I try to count files in a folder which have the same name pattern. In this case every signs before "_" is the important part (the pattern).

**Example (c:\temp)**
ct24fe_2016-03-01.txt
ct24fe_2016-03-04.txt
ct24fe_2016-03-08.txt
ct24fe_2016-04-01.txt
ct24fe_2016-04-04.txt
xye4ka_2015-03-04.txt
xye4ka_2015-03-08.txt
xye4ka_2015-03-10.txt
xye4ka_2015-03-15.txt
xye4ka_2015-04-01.txt
xye4ka_2015-04-04.txt
zzztgf_2014-04-16.txt
zzztgf_2014-04-18.txt
zzztgf_2014-04-19.txt
zzztgf_2014-05-15.txt

The result should be:

**Name | Count**
ct24fe  | 5
xye4ka  | 6
zzztgf  | 4

How could I do this?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Have you tried anything we can help you with? It is expected that you would have tried something as SO is not a code writing service. That being said you need to look at `Group-Object` and I think a duplicate exists for this already.

Comment: Hi Matt, shure I try the Group-Object. but I have problems with the separation of the string and collect/count/group the results. I searched for it but I could find only an example for the group by the same date.

Answer (score 2):

`Group-Object` supports scriptblocks for the `-Property` argument, you can pipe the files directly to it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp |Group-Object {$_.Name -split '_' |Select -First 1} -NoElement
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've come up with this:

```
$input = "your stuff"
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$input | % {$array.Add($_.split("_")[0])}

$array | Group-Object -NoElement
```

Comment: I will keep this solution with arrays in mind, works perfect. This solution is a little bit slower than the soulution of @mjolinor

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
(Get-ChildItem c:\temp -Name) -replace '_.*' | Group-Object -NoElement
```

Comment: Add `|%{write-host $_.name "|" $_.count}` to the end of this to get the exact requested output format.